# ¿Como mostrar N cantidad de Labels al presionar un boton?

Tags: vb.net

Buen dia.

Estoy programando en .NET y estoy en una situacion en la que al presionar un Button llamado Button2, quiero crear un label e ir posicionando uno debajo de otro (todo esto en tiempo de EJECUCION). Tengo hasta el momento este codigo insertado en el evento Button2_Click :

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim Label1 As Label = New Label

        Label1.Text = "Esto es un label" 

        Label1.Location = New Point(9, y)
        Label1.ForeColor = Color.Black
        y += 9
        Console.WriteLine(y)

        Me.Controls.Add(Label1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Se supone que como la variable "y" va a estar cambiando cada vez que presione el Button, un label nuevo deberia aparecer debajo del label anterior pero veo que eso suceda. Solo me aparece un label y al seguir dando clicks en el Button, ya no aparece ningun otro label y el que está creado no se mueve de lugar. Es decir que solo me crea 1 Label

¿Que estoy haciendo mal? Si alguien pudiera ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: 9 parece bastante poco, igual simplemente no la distingues una encima de otra. O esta reiniciando las pantalla en algún otro sitio.

Comment: Ya te ha dado la solución SJuan76... prueba a usar 'y += Label1.Height' para que el incremento sea la altura del label creado y veras como funciona....

Comment: Ya lo intenté y no funciono. Alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Que has intentado?, porque estoy seguro que funciona... De todos modos, mira [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/412638/c%c3%b3mo-acceder-a-un-label-que-se-encuentra-en-un-user-control-en-vb-net].

Answer (score 0):

Crea un Método Para Crear Etiquetas Dinámicamente y Dales Sus Propiedades...

```
Public Sub CrearLabel(ByVal Left As Integer, ByVal Top As Integer)
    Dim NuevoLabel As New Label
    Me.Controls.Add(NuevoLabel)
    NuevoLabel.Left = Left
    NuevoLabel.Top = Top
    NuevoLabel.Text = "Hola"
    NuevoLabel.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    CrearLabel(1, 20)
    CrearLabel(1, 40)
    CrearLabel(1, 60)
End Sub
```