# ¿Cómo acceder a un label que se encuentra en un user control en vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, usercontrol

Tengo un user control, con varios label's, la idea es mandarlo llamar y que en esa llamada se especifiquen los valores de los label's.

```
Private Sub CargarControl()
    Dim NuevaTarjeta As Control
    NuevaTarjeta = New TarjetaProyecto
    Dim MiTipo As System.Type = NuevaTarjeta.GetType
    NuevaTarjeta.Name = MiTipo.Name & Convert.ToString(iContador)
    NuevaTarjeta.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(7, 146)
    NuevaTarjeta.Width = 489

    Me.Contenedor.Controls.Add(NuevaTarjeta)

    iContador += 1
End Sub
```

Y en el user control pensé algo así:

```
Public Class TarjetaProyecto

Public Sub CargarDatos(ByVal Responsable As String, ByVal Titulo As String, ByVal Inicio As DateTime, ByVal Compromiso As DateTime, ByVal Quedan As Integer, ByVal Progreso As Integer)
    txtResponsable.Text = Responsable
    txtTitulo.Text = Titulo
    txtInicio.Text = Inicio.ToString()
    txtCompromiso.Text = Compromiso.ToString()
    txtQuedan.Text = "Quedan " & Quedan & " días."
    txtProgreso.Width = Progreso
End Sub
```

End Class

De tal forma que al cargar el control que se llama NuevaTarjeta, pues especifique lo que quiero mostrar de los label, pero no se como se hace esto. ¿alguien podría orientarme?

Comment: Esta perfecto eso. Que es lo que nonpudiste hacer?

Comment: ¿Como le hago desde el método CargarControl, para enlazar al de CargarDatos... Es decir intente esto:     NuevaTarjeta.CargarDatos   y pues desde ahi ya error, ya que CargarDatos, no es unmiembro de Nueva Tarjeta

Comment: Llamar a ese metodo no funciona?

Comment: Me dice que CargarDatos, no es un miembro de NuevaTarjeta

Comment: Tarjetaproyecto es de tipo control? Donde esta tu control de usuario? Ahi deberia estar ese metodo... ese es el problema

Comment: Es correcto TarjetaProyecto es mi user control, En el procedimiento que uso para cargarlo uso la variable NuevaTarjeta de tipo TarjetaProyecto

Comment: Entonces porque no definis nuevatarjeta como tarjetaproyecto, y de ahi llamas al metodo? Nuevatarjeta.cargardatos() deberia funcionar. Si no, el problema esta en como definiste todo

Comment: Es debido a que se genera dinámicamente en tiempo de ejecución, si le especifico NuevaTarjeta, ¿como indico cual de los controles del mismo tipo?

Comment: Tenes que llevar un control de alguna forma de los controles que vas agregando. Si es un array de controles, tienen un indice. Si solo lo agregas, despues tenes que poder ubicarlo de alguna forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa las propiedades. Veamos un ejemplo.

Tenemos un User Control formado por, entre otras cosas, por dos labels, uno de titulo y otro de cuerpo. Le hemos puesto un picturebox en una esquina donde le daremos funcionalidad para lanzar un evento.

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Su codigo es muy simple. Solo consta de tres PROPIEDADES, sería Id, Titulo y Cuerpo. Tambien definimos un evento, que emitirá un dato de tipo numérico, pensado para el ID de la tarjeta. Cuando hacemos click en la imagen, lanzamo el evento:

```
Public Class UserControl1

Event Editar(ByVal TarjetaId As Integer) ' Definimos un evento llamado Editar con el tipo que emitirá

Public Property Id As Integer 'Propiedad para almacenar un IDentificador

Private tituloValue As String

Public Property Titulo() As String
    Get
        Return tituloValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        tituloValue = value
        LbTitulo.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Private cuerpoValue As String
Public Property Cuerpo() As String
    Get
        Return cuerpoValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        cuerpoValue = value
        LbCuerpo.Text = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    RaiseEvent Editar(Me.Id) ' Al hacer Click en la imagen, lanzamos el evento
End Sub
End Class
```

Como puedes ver, cuando asignamos un valor a la propiedad (set), ya le damos el valor al label que nos interesa, de este modo no necesitas metodos.

Vamos a probarlo con el siguiente código, creamos un nuevo formulario y le ponemos un boton, para que cada vez que lo pulsemos, añada una tarjeta nueva con unas propiedades iniciales y si pulsamos en el lapiz de cada tarjeta, pues lanzará el evento:

```
Public Class Form1

Private y As Integer = 10
Private numTarjeta As Integer = 0

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim tarjeta As New UserControl1
    numTarjeta += 1
    tarjeta.Id = numTarjeta 'Asignamos un ID a la tarjeta
    tarjeta.Name = "Tarjeta_" & numTarjeta
    tarjeta.Titulo = "Titulo de la Tarjeta " & numTarjeta
    tarjeta.Cuerpo = "Esto es un cometario de prueba. Se " &
                     "trata de la tarjeta número " & numTarjeta

    tarjeta.Location = New Point(10, y)
    y += tarjeta.Height + 5

    ' Creamos un controlador para escuchar el evento
    ' que mandaremos al metodo EditarTarjeta
    AddHandler tarjeta.Editar, AddressOf EditarTarjeta ' Creamos un controlador para escuchar el evento

    Me.Controls.Add(tarjeta)
End Sub


Private Sub EditarTarjeta(ID As String)
    MsgBox("Has pulsado la tarjeta " & ID)
End Sub

End Class
```

El resultado sería, más o menos así:

[image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estimado Vicente Sanchez, primeramente muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de explicar de forma tan clara la solución a mi problema, ahorita solo lo estoy leyendo pero parece que es esa la solución. Ayer ya había eliminado el form, buscando otra forma de hacerlo por lo que voy a volver a implementar con base a lo que indicas.

Comment: Mientras lo hago, solo quisiera aprovechar, ¿como puedo añadir una función a un botón? Verás, la tarjeta debe tener la funcionalidad de editarse, por lo que añadiendo un botón con un evento, poder abrir otro form ya a detalle. Con que pase el id, es suficiente pues yo con eso, cargo todo desde la bd.

Comment: Es una explicación un poco extensa, pero sencilla. Se trata de definir un evento en la tarjeta, voy a crear otra respuesta porque es un poco lioso por aqui...

Comment: He editado la respuesta con un ejemplo de emisión de evento, ya lo tienes que adaptar a lo que quieras... Un saludo.

Comment: Definitivamente es toda la respuesta a lo que necesito. La verdad hay muchas aplicaciones para este tema y con tu ejemplo se resuelve. Gracias